# minimal collapsing without GCH

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Suppose $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal.  Does there necessarily exist a poset $\mathbb P$ that collapses $\kappa^+$ while preserving all other cardinals?

Comment: I'm assuming that you have $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$ in this case, or just a general collapse?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, $2^{<\kappa} \leq \kappa^+$ implies that the canonical $Col(\kappa,\kappa^+)$ works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For $\kappa=\aleph_1,$ the answer is yes, and is due to Abraham: "[On Forcing Without the Continuum Hypothesis](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2273457?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)". See also Todorcevic's paper "[A note on the Proper Forcing Axiom](http://www.math.toronto.edu/~stevo/Todorcevic_Note_On_PFA.pdf)", for a different proof.

For $\kappa=\aleph_2,$ the answer is yes, and is due to Aspero: "[A forcing notion collapsing $\aleph_3$ and preserving all other cardinals](https://www.uea.ac.uk/~bfe12ncu/collapsing-aleph3.pdf)".

For other cardinals, the answer seems to be open.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer.  I will give it a few days before accepting to see if anyone can report a recent breakthrough.

Comment: @MonroeEskew I believe the following is true: Suppose $V$ is a generic extension of a $GCH$ model by set forcing (in $V$ the continuum function may be quite complicated), and let $\kappa$ be regular in $V$. Then there is a forcing notion which collapses $\kappa^+$ and preserves all other cardinals. The idea I have to prove this is to use Gitik's piste forcing, but I never tried to write the details and see if it works or not.